# Why does a program become broken when a character is input when prompted to input an integer value?

Tags: c++

Example:

```
int i=0;
do {
    cin >> i;
    if(!isdigit(i)) cout << "Error. Must be an integer\n\n";
}
while(cin.fail());
```

If a character rather than an integer was input by the user, the program would break and go into some infinite loop for some reason. Why is this? Is there no way to prevent it from happening? the isdigit() function doesn't seem to work well with `int` variables, only with `char` variables.

Comment: It won't go into an infinite loop with just that code inside `main`. Simply, the extraction will fail and put the stream in a bad state.

Comment: Show your actual (minimal) code that gets into this state, and someone will tell you what the bug is.

Comment: The program doesn't **become** broken; it **is** broken because it doesn't handle incorrect input correctly.

Comment: Still not compilable code... As to the actual question, trying to parse something that fails to parse (e.g.int expected, "aaa" given on stdin) will set the `bad` bit, and no IO will happen until you reset it. You need to do something like `if (std::cin.fail()) {/*do something about failure*/;std::cin.clear();}

Comment: There are so many errors in this small code sample! Don't you have a textbook that explains the basics??

Comment: @Arkadiy Failing to parse the input correctly sets `failbit`, not `badbit`.

Comment: @James Kanze: Sorry, right you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused about how input works.  When you write

```
std::cin >> i;
```

and `i` is an `int`, the input stream will extract the text for
an integral value: it will skip whitespace, then extract
a possible sign, then one or more digits.  It will then convert
this text into an `int`, and store it where requested.  If it
doesn't find text in the appropriate format, it will set an
error status (`failbit`), which will remain set until you clear
it.  And it will *not* modify `i`; you must always check that
input has succeeded before using the variable input.

`isdigit`, on the other hand, has undefined behavior *unless*
the integer it is passed is in the range `[0,UCHAR_MAX]`.  (Note
that range.  It means that you cannot simply pass it a `char`.)

It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  If it's just
enter an `int`:

```
int i;
while ( !(std::cin >> i) ) {
    std::cout << "Error: integer wanted" << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();       //  Clear error...
    std::cin.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' );   //  And ignore characters which caused it 
                                        //  (up until next '\n')
}
```

If you want a single digit:

```
int i = std::cin.get();
while ( i != EOF && !isdigit( i ) ) {
    std::cout << "Error, single digit wanted" << std::endl;
    i = std::cin.get();
}
char ch = i;        //  NOW (and only now) can you convert into int.
```

`std::cin.get()` returns an `int`, in order to handle the out of
band value `EOF`.  The `int` in guaranteed to be in the range
`[0...UCHAR_MAX]`, or to be `EOF`, so you can pass it directly
to `isdigit`.  Only once you've finished these tests should you
convert it into a `char` (since a digit is a character).

Answer (score 2):

You **always** need to check **after** reading that your input was successful, e.g.

```
if (std::cin >> i) {
    // process input
}
```

If the input fails `std::ios_failbit` is set. While this flag is set the stream won't accept any input and convert to `false`. To clear the error flags you use

```
std::cin.clear();
```

Clearing the error flags won't remove the offending character. You'll need to get rid of them, e.g., using

```
std:: ignore();
```

Comment: No comments about his use of `isdigit` on an `int` read with `>>`? :-)

Comment: @JamesKanze: using `isdigit()` with an `int` is better than using it with a `char`! It just won't yield `true` on the values where expected. Checking the input its use becomes unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Typically (historically, at least), `isdigit()` was used on `int`.  An `int` returned from `getc()` or `std::istream::get()`, however, and _not_ one read with `fscanf( "%d" )` or `somestream >> someInt`.  It's undefined behavior to call `isdigit()` with an `int` whose value is not in the range `[0, UCHAR_MAX]` (with the exception of `EOF`), and you certainly can't count on your input source to respect this.

Answer (score 0):

The above code certainly doesn't create an infinite loop. But the loop happens usually when a digit is expected and a non-digit is given, so the characters in the buffer will stay there and the stream is in an bad state. This will happen until the stream is appropriately cleared, so that the stdio can continue to read according to the format specification. Of course the loop has to be done iny our program, as stdio is not looping on it's own.

To clear the input and ingore what is left there you can use this:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore();
```